# Incoming ZeroMQ traffic dropped by server due to NAT?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have a ZMQ server listening on port 12345 TCP. When another server connects on that port locally or via VM it works fine, but if I try from a remote server that has to go through port forwarding on my Fios firewall it just bombs. The packets are showing up in Wireshark but ZMQ just ignores them. Is there anyway to get past this?

Comment: What do you mean "ZMQ just ignores them" - what do the logs say?

Comment: It doesn't show anything in the logs. It's like nothing got to the zmq. The packet made it to the server fine but it's like it's not really listening.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to bind more than once to the same port number, either from the same process or another.

ZMQ should give a failure when you issue bind with a port number already in use.  Are you checking return codes?

Comment: The issue is not that ZMQ is binding on different ports, the issue is remote connections don't reach ZMQ.

Comment: The OP is looking for causes of traffic not arriving.  Given that you should be only able to bind once on a given port, the additional 'server' mentioned seems to show a misunderstanding of how things work.

Comment: Even if that were true, from this statement _"when another server connects on that port locally or via VM it works fine"_; this is not the problem. Either way, your answer should really be a comment.

Comment: It seems like there is an issue in OSX for listening to external connections. I redid it on Ubuntu and it worked fine so it's clearly OSX. It's like there's a firewall blocking it but wireshark shows packets coming in so it can't be that. Maybe an OSX 10.9 bug?